# How can i write " in php

Tags: php, quotes

```
function wrap($str) {
    $str="[@id=\"".$str."\"]";
    return($str);
}

$str="Hi";
$str=wrap($str);
```

I would have `$str` like `[@id="Hi"]`, but i have `$str` like `[@id=\"Hi\"]`
How could i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works as expected, no need to change quotes to single ticks or remove the second pair of double quotes.

Probably the backslashes are added later. If you just `echo $str;` after your snippet it shows this in a browser

```
[@id="Hi"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str='[@id="'.$str.'"]';
```

replace `"` with `'`

Comment: or remove a set of quotes and dots `$str="[@id=\"$str\"]";` would give the same output `[@id="Hi"]` and using slightly less code ;-)